# Filter rows by condition applied to indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with dates as indices:

```
            VL
2018-02-05  101.56093
2018-12-31  95.87728
2019-01-04  96.29820
2019-01-11  97.23475
2019-01-18  98.39828
2019-01-25  98.66896
2019-01-31  99.12407
2019-02-01  99.13224
2019-02-08  99.06382
2019-02-15  99.79966
```

I need to filter the rows so that, **for each row with date `D`, keep it if the row with `D-7` exists in the DataFrame**.

Example:

- `2019-02-15` would remain, because `2019-02-08` is present
- `2019-01-31` would be filtered as `2019-01-24` is not present.

I've implemented this already using a loop but I'm wondering if there is a more pandas oriented way of doing this kind of filtering.

Comment: Actually the example data is a `Series`, although the real example is a DataFrame with more than one column. If that is relevant I'll edit the question.

Comment: Can you paste your expected output to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `pd.Timedelta` and `isin`:

```
df[(df['date'] - pd.Timedelta(days=7)).isin(df['date'])]
```

Output:

```
        date        VL
3 2019-01-11  97.23475
4 2019-01-18  98.39828
5 2019-01-25  98.66896
7 2019-02-01  99.13224
8 2019-02-08  99.06382
9 2019-02-15  99.79966
```

If date is in the index use this:

```
df[(df.index - pd.Timedelta(days=7)).isin(df.index)]
```

Output:

```
                  VL
date                
2019-01-11  97.23475
2019-01-18  98.39828
2019-01-25  98.66896
2019-02-01  99.13224
2019-02-08  99.06382
2019-02-15  99.79966
```

Comment: There is no `date` column. Instead the dates are the DataFrame indices.